# Can i use Node js, Websocket and php in the same apache server?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, websocket

I was wondering if its possible create a website combined with NodeJs, Websocket and php in the same Apache server. Is there any documentation that can i read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In the same Apache server", No.  node.js does not run in Apache.  It runs by itself.

But, you can use multiple technologies on the same server.  For starters, you could have two completely separate web servers running on separate ports, one that was Apache + PHP + webSocket and another that was node.js + webSocket.

But, node.js does not use Apache.  Instead, node.js would typically be configured to be it's own web server all by itself.  So, you don't typically run an Apache server and have some requests through it go to PHP and some go to node.js.

Using PHP and node.js together depends entirely upon what you're trying to do with them.  You could have your web server as a node.js server and then have some requests that node.js receives actually execute some PHP and get the results from running a PHP script.  And, you could do the reverse too with a PHP script fielding the request and then manually running a node.js script for some requests.

To answer any more fully, we need to know what you're really trying to do with PHP, node.js and webSockets.

FYI, you could set up an NGINX proxy on port 80 and configure it to direct some requests to your Apache/PHP server (running on a different port) and other requests to your node.js server (running on a different port).  Incoming webSocket requests would then be directed to one of the two servers.

Comment: I al trying to project a simple Social network with chat and real time video. I know that Websocket can run only with nodejs, right?

Comment: @PazzoTotale - webSocket can run with PHP too.  You could do your whole app with node.js and webSocket.

Comment: My problem Is the server configuration, because i have few experience with it. In the past i used servers with default configuration

Comment: @PazzoTotale - That's not something we can help you with given the information you've provided.  I've answered your question about what is possible.  If you want to do some of your own research on the topic, then open a new question that describes what you're trying to do and ask how to do everything with node.js + webSocket or how to do everything you're trying to do with Apache + PHP + webSocket, then maybe somebody can help you.  But, you will have to fully describe your app requirements, show the community that you've done a bunch of your own research and ask a specific question.